# Highlight debug functions

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, code-inspection

I use PhpStorm for a while now, and it's code inspection and syntax highlighting is great! To further extend this feature, I am looking for a way to alert myself of 'debug functions'. I frequently use functions like `var_dump()`, `exit()` or `echo '<pre>',print($var),'</pre>'`. Unfortunately, I also frequently forget these when deploying some code.

Is it possible to add custom highlighting in PhpStorm for some defined functions with the Inspection-feature, so I am visually notified that some debugging-code is still present? Or a plugin or other feature to accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install and use **Php Inspections (EA Extended) plugin**
2. Once installed -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
3. One of the inspections this plugin provides called `Forgotten debug statements` -- find it there (hint: there is a search field -- use it)
4. This inspection will highlight some standard debug related functions + you can add your own function names.

**P.S.**
This inspection works with PHP functions only -- it will not find constructions like `echo '<pre>',print($var),'</pre>'`.

**BTW** -- why don't you try Xdebug/Zend Debugger for a proper debug experience?

Comment: Absolutely. I would also suggest using judicious logging (which can naturally throttle down to bare-bone minimum when deployed to the production environment). I compose-in `log4php` : it works well for me.