# PHP Warnings / Errors on commit

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I would like to setup a warning system so that when I commit a file I am warned if it contains a certain string.

I have seen that TODO is one of the values under `Preferences -> Editor -> TODO` but would also like a warning if for example I have used `dump()` (as it caused an exception in our live environment).

Has anyone got any experience about how to best set this up?

Thanks for any pointer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801178/783119 -- you can use that approach to highlight such functions/methods as errors -- IDE should warn you when submitting such code.

Comment: Probably a PHP code linter/style enforcer as a git commit hook would be the best idea. This way it's also IDE-independent.