# Add new rules for color and fonts in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to make PhpStorm highlight some particular function with different color? I would like to have all my var_dumps and some other functions to be easily spotted in code by changing font or background colors for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make PhpStorm highlight some particular function with different color?

No custom coloring for random text or custom keywords/entities is available.

You may watch [IDEABKL-7247](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7247) and [IDEABKL-5473](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473) tickets (and related) for that.

> I would like to have all my var_dumps and some other functions to be easily spotted

You may install **"Php Inspection (EA Extended)" plugin** -- it has one inspection that targets "forgotten debug statements" (they will be marked with Error level severity so hard to miss). List of such functions is fully customizable.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801178/783119 for a bit more info.

Comment: thanks, this plugin will highlight these functions only after running inspection, not in the realtime, right ?

Comment: All inspections are on-the-fly -- while file is opened in editor. But you can also run them separately on demand (e.g. on whole folder etc -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-inspections.html)

Comment: P.S. Why not use debugger (xdebug) instead of much less convenient var_dump way?

Comment: well, that was just an example, when I thought of this i was using file_put_content actually, just thrown a var_dump as an example :) in fact i would love to use such feature for any function, or even better any text occurrence (i understand now there is no way for that)

once again: thanks man, seems it will be excellent solution :)